# alpine refuses to save imap password

Tags: alpine-mail

I have compiled alpine 2.20 with option `--with-passfile=/home/fuji/.alpine.pwd` and when I type the imap password of gmail, I get my mails but when it comes to save the password, i get the following debug messages:

```
14:05:34.653790
Looking for passfile "/home/fuji/.alpine.pwd"

14:05:34.655538
q_status_message(Attempting to encrypt password file)

14:05:34.656276
q_status_message(Refusing to write non-encrypted password file)

14:05:34.656322
IMAP DEBUG 14:05:34.656322: <suppressed>
```

and

```
ll ~/.alpine.pwd
-rw------- 1 fuji opera 0 Dec 20 17:42 .alpine.pwd
```

How can I save that password?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, your `--with-passfile` option is wrong, it's supposed to be relative to your home dir, so just `--with-passfile=.alpine.pwd`. Not sure if that's the cause, though.

Comment: No, absolute path is fine.
I had to create a ssl certificate and install the file in ~/.alpine-smime/private, ~/.alpine-smime/public and ~/.alpine-smime/ca. Only then will the imap password be saved in .alpine.pwd .

Comment: @FujiSan Nice find! Could you please [answer this question yourself](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and close it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to create a ssl certificate and install the file in ~/.alpine-smime/private, ~/.alpine-smime/public and ~/.alpine-smime/ca. Only then will the imap password be saved in .alpine.pwd .

Comment: would you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

For me it works (with the Debian standard build version 2.20), using the commandline flag -passfile.

```
touch .yourpassfile
alpine -passfile .yourpassfile
```

After giving your password for IMAP authentication it will now ask you if you want to save this to the given passfile. Say Y. Now everytime run alpine with  the command above (or make a shortcut for it) and it will automatically authenticate to your IMAP server.

Answer (score 1):

Alpine needs an ssl certificate to save passwords. Here's what I did to make it work (careful, change the `pass:x` value to something you consider secure; you can also omit the argument and type it when requested. Alpine will ask you some times for this password).

```
cd
touch .pine-passfile
mkdir ~/temp-ssl
cd ~/temp-ssl
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -passin pass:x -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:x -days 3650 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
mkdir -p ~/.alpine-smime/private ~/.alpine-smime/public ~/.alpine-smime/ca
mv server.key ~/.alpine-smime/private
cp server.crt ~/.alpine-smime/ca
mv server.crt ~/.alpine-smime/public
rm server.csr
cd
rmdir ~/temp-ssl
```

For the second `openssl` command you have to enter at least one field, like the *Country Name*. You can leave the *Challenge Password* field empty when asked by the end of that same command.

This time Alpine should save your credentials.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a complete answer. It still refuses to write the password file.

Answer (score 0):

I found it depends on the correct compiled passfile name to use. To find out, issue

```
$ alpine -version

[..]
--with-passfile=.alpine.passfile
[...]
```

So `touch ~/.alpine.passfile`. Then reopen alpine, enter password. It will prompt for saving it.